# EKEvent adds same events to calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekevent

I have been testing this code to add a calendar to IOS Cal App, and also add some events to that specific calendar in the app.

I have an Ipad with IOS7, iCloud disabled.

First problem is when I create calendar I can't see newly created calendar in iPad's iCal App,Isn't that app supposed to show all calendars even if they are not added to iCloud?

second problem is my code keep adding same events every time I call that code.

Lets say I call the add function and it adds 3 events successfully firs time, next time when call that function with same events it supposed to skip adding but it adds that 3 events to calendar again now I have duplicate events, and so on...

```
-(void) initCalendar:(NSDictionary *)dataDict
{
    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if([self.eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
        // iOS 6 and later
        [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted){
                //---- codes here when user allow your app to access theirs' calendar.
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                self.isCalendarAccepted=YES;
                NSLog(@"self.isCalendarAccepted=YES;");
                if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Calendar"] == nil) // Create Calendar if Needed
                {
                    EKSource *theSource = nil;

                    for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources) {
                        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"]) {
                            theSource = source;
                            NSLog(@"iCloud Store Source");
                            break;
                        } else {
                            for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources) {
                                if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) {
                                    theSource = source;
                                    NSLog(@"ios Local Store Source");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    //EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
                    EKCalendar *calendar =[EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:self.eventStore];
                    calendar.title = @"My App Name";
                    if (theSource) {
                        calendar.source = theSource;
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Error: Local source not available");
                        return;
                    }
                    NSError *errorCalendar = nil;
                    BOOL result = [self.eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&errorCalendar];
                    if (result) {
                        NSLog(@"Saved calendar to event store.");
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:calendar.calendarIdentifier forKey:@"Calendar"];
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Error saving calendar: %@.", errorCalendar);
                    }

                }
                //start adding event to calendar
                [self addSelectedOwnEventsToCalendar:dataDict];
            }
        }];
    }


}

-(void)addSelectedOwnEventsToCalendar:(NSDictionary *)dataDict
{

            // Create a new event... save and commit
            NSError *error = nil;

            EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];


            myEvent.allDay = NO;
            myEvent.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSString *startDateFormatted=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"start_date"],[dataDict objectForKey:@"starts"]];
            startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDateFormatted];

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter1  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            NSString *endDateFormatted=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"end_date"],[dataDict objectForKey:@"ends"]];
            endDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:endDateFormatted];

            //compare dates
            NSComparisonResult result = [startDate compare:endDate];
            if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
            } else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
            }  else {
                //the same
                endDate=[startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
            }

            myEvent.startDate=startDate;
            myEvent.endDate = endDate;
            myEvent.title = [dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"];
            myEvent.calendar = [self.eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Calendar"]];
            myEvent.location=[dataDict objectForKey:@"location"];



            NSArray *cals = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent];
            NSPredicate *predicateForEventsOnHolidayDate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:cals]; // nil will search through all calendars

            NSArray *eventsOnHolidayDate = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicateForEventsOnHolidayDate];
            //NSLog(@"eventsOnHolidayDate %@",eventsOnHolidayDate);

            BOOL eventExists = NO;

            for (EKEvent *eventToCheck in eventsOnHolidayDate) {
                NSLog(@"eventToCheck.title %@",eventToCheck.title);
                NSLog(@"event_id %@",[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"]);
                if ([eventToCheck.title isEqualToString:[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"]]) {
                    eventExists = YES;
                    NSLog(@"Event Already Exists");
                }
            }
            //save eventts
            if (eventExists == NO) {
                [self.eventStore saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
                if (!error) {
                   // NSLog(@"the event saved and committed correctly with identifier %@", myEvent.eventIdentifier);

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"there was an error saving and committing the event");
                    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                    error = nil;

                }


            }
}
```

When I first run the code NSlog says `(@"ios Local Store Source");`

What am I missing?

Note: Code is working on  simulator(Ipad ios 7) most of the time, I assuming something wrong with `[NSUserDefaults]` ?

Comment: Note [accessing `self` in a block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16) is a memory leak.

Comment: I've noticed that each time, you're setting `startDate` to the current date, which may be cutting out an event that has already started from the predicate (try setting the date to the very beginning of the day?). Also, I'd avoid using the `title` property for unique identifiers -- use `eventIdentifier`. On another note, @johnnieb, accessing `self` in a block only results in a memory leak if `self` retains that block (retain cycle) -- this block doesn't seem to be strongly retained by anything.

Answer (score 2):

First, see the discussion points about duplicates in the [calendarItemExternalIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendarItem/calendarItemExternalIdentifier) documentation and determine if any of them apply.

Then, take a look at the following suggestions:

1. The [calendar identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendar/calendarIdentifier) can change. Ensure that the saved version for key `Calendar` in `NSUserDefaults` is the same as the one being accessed in `addSelectedOwnEventsToCalendar:`.
2. When retrieving the *calendar identifier* from the `NSUserDefaults` make sure that it’s valid.
3. Try using the `saveEvent:span:error:` method without the `commit` parameter. I’ve had problems using the save event method that takes a commit argument in the past.

Lastly, I believe that iOS calendar access authorization can only be tested on an iOS device, which is probably why it’s working in the simulator.

Comment: Yes, Calendar testing needs to be done on a iOS device. It's a real pain and driving me nuts, but it's the only way Apple supports.